# How to display data from both sides of a 1 to 1 relationship in a view and update the correct table on Submit?

Tags: html, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 2 model classes named Member & Envelope shown below where Member has a 1 to 1 relationship with Envelope:

```
namespace Mapping.Models
{
    public class Member
    {
        [Key]
        public int MemberId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Mailing Name")]
        [StringLength(250)]
        public string? MemberMailingName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Family Name")]
        [StringLength(250)]
        public string? MemberFamilyName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Status")]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string? MemberStatus { get; set; }

        // Navigation Properties
        public virtual Envelope? Envelope { get; set; }
    }

    public class Envelope
    {
        [Key]
        public int EnvelopeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Envelope Number")]
        public int EnvelopeNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I pass the Member model to the Edit view, it recognizes that there is an Envelope associated with it.

I have 2 problems:

1. I can't display the EnvelopeNumber from the Envelope in Edit fields - it shows up blank
2. I want to be able to update the Envelope table when the user clicks Submit (There is a separate  and Submit button for the Member and the Envelope).

Below is the MembersController method for Edit and the Edit.cshtml that I'm using (Please don't judge the crappy HTML - I'll clean it all up once it works correctly!)

Thanks in Advance for any help with this!!

Edit Method in MembersController:

```
// GET: Members/Edit/5
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var member = await _context.Member.FindAsync(id);
    if (member == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View(member);
}
```

Edit.cshtml:

```
@model StJosephMapping.Models.Member

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>Member</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="MemberId" />
            <span>
                <table style="float: left;">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:25%;">
                            <label asp-for="MemberMailingName" class="control-label"></label>
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:25%;">
                            <label asp-for="MemberFamilyName" class="control-label"></label>
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:25%;">
                            <label asp-for="MemberStatus" class="control-label"></label>
                        </th>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="MemberMailingName" class="form-control" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="MemberFamilyName" class="form-control" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="MemberStatus" class="form-control" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span asp-validation-for="MemberMailingName" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span asp-validation-for="MemberFamilyName" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span asp-validation-for="MemberStatus" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table style="display: inline-block;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 26px;">
                                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </span>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<h4>Envelope</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="MemberId" />
            <span>
                <table style="float: left;">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:25%;">
                            <label asp-for="Envelope.EnvelopeNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="Envelope.EnvelopeNumber" class="form-control" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span asp-validation-for="Envelope.EnvelopeNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table style="display: inline-block;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 26px;">
                                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </span>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't display the EnvelopeNumber from the Envelope in Edit fields - it shows up blank

You can do this by using the `Include` method in Entity Framework Core:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null || _context.Member == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    //var member = await _context.Member.FindAsync(id);
    var member = await _context.Member.Include(a => a.Envelope).FirstOrDefaultAsync(a=>a.MemberId==id);
    if (member == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View(member);
}
```

> I want to be able to update the Envelope table when the user clicks
> Submit (There is a separate and Submit button for the Member and the
> Envelope).

You need to ensure that the `EnvelopeId` is included in the form so that the controller can identify which `Envelope` needs to be updated.

Change your Edit.cshtml like below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="MemberId" />
            <span>
                <table style="float: left;">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:25%;">
                            <label asp-for="MemberMailingName" class="control-label"></label>
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:25%;">
                            <label asp-for="MemberFamilyName" class="control-label"></label>
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:25%;">
                            <label asp-for="MemberStatus" class="control-label"></label>
                        </th>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="MemberMailingName" class="form-control" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="MemberFamilyName" class="form-control" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="MemberStatus" class="form-control" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span asp-validation-for="MemberMailingName" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span asp-validation-for="MemberFamilyName" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span asp-validation-for="MemberStatus" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table style="display: inline-block;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 26px;">
                                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </span>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<h4>Envelope</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <!--   change here  -->           
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Envelope.EnvelopeId" />
            <span>
                <table style="float: left;">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:25%;">
                            <label asp-for="Envelope.EnvelopeNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="Envelope.EnvelopeNumber" class="form-control" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span asp-validation-for="Envelope.EnvelopeNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table style="display: inline-block;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 26px;">
                                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </span>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Edit action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id,Member member)
{
    if(member.MemberId!=0)
    {
        if (id != member.MemberId)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //edit the member
            try
            {
                _context.Update(member);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!MemberExists(member.MemberId))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            //do you stuff...
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //edit the envelope
        if(member.Envelope!=null)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(member.Envelope);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            //do you stuff...
        }
    }
    return View(member);
}
```